# Wireshark filters: Difference between !(ip.addr == 192.0.2.1) and (ip.addr != 192.0.2.1)

Tags: wireshark

Regarding the filters in Wireshark, what is the differencebetween !(ip.addr == 192.0.2.1) and (ip.addr != 192.0.2.1)? When check the result, it's not giving the same result and I don't know why...

Plus, when I apply the filter (ip.addr != 192.0.2.1) appears a different color as background in filters (Yellow).
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiZxE.png)

Does anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html, section 6.4.6

Answer (score 3):

In Boolean Logic, `A not equals B` and `not A equals B` are the same test.

But, the relevant part of the [WireShark documentation linked by Jürgen Thelen](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html) explains that in WireShark, `ip.addr` covers both the source and destination field, so the test is more like:

```
not ((A or B) equals C)
```

which filters packets where source or destination match, and then hides them (correctly).

Compared to:

```
(A or B) not equals C
```

which filters packets where either the source OR the destination is not C, and that's every packet, so it shows every packet.

> 6.4.6. A Common Mistake
>   Using the != operator on combined expressions like eth.addr, ip.addr, tcp.port, and udp.port will probably not work as expected.
>
> Often people use a filter string to display something like ip.addr == 1.2.3.4 which will display all packets containing the IP address 1.2.3.4.
>
> Then they use ip.addr != 1.2.3.4 to see all packets not containing the IP address 1.2.3.4 in it. Unfortunately, this does not do the expected.
>
> Instead, that expression will even be true for packets where either source or destination IP address equals 1.2.3.4. The reason for this, is that the expression ip.addr != 1.2.3.4 must be read as “the packet contains a field named ip.addr with a value different from 1.2.3.4”. As an IP datagram contains both a source and a destination address, the expression will evaluate to true whenever at least one of the two addresses differs from 1.2.3.4.

The reason it takes a yellow background is because of this potentially surprising behaviour, and there is a matching warning at the bottom of the screen, in the status bar, suggesting checking the user guide for more details:

[image: WireShark status bar warning]

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose we want to filter out any traffic to or from 10.43.54.65. We might try the following: 
>    `ip.addr != 10.43.54.65`.
>   This translates to "pass all traffic except for traffic with a source IPv4 address of 10.43.54.65 and a destination IPv4 address of 10.43.54.65".
>
> `! ( ip.addr == 10.43.54.65 )`.
>   This translates to "pass any traffic except with a source IPv4 address of 10.43.54.65 or a destination IPv4 address of 10.43.54.65".

You can see more on this at [Wireshark: DisplayFilters](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters).